# Why is this displaying None?

Tags: python

```
def characterLine(firstChar,secondChar,phrase):
     '\n' + ((str(firstChar)+str(secondChar))*(len(phrase)/2)+len(phrase)%2* firstChar)
```

So the second part of the code will display but when I try to concatenate it with a line skip, it displays "None."

Can someone explain to me as to why this is happening?

Comment: We need the full code, properly formatted.

Comment: @Matt Ball: `s/concatentate/concatenate`?

Comment: Why are you writing Python code like that?

Comment: def characterLine(firstChar,secondChar,phrase):
    '\n' + ((str(firstChar)+str(secondChar))*(len(phrase)/2)+len(phrase)%2* firstChar)

Comment: You've almost certainly got operator precedence issues there. Trying to work out what the types will be, I get `str + int` inside the parenthesis at the end, which doesn't make sense?

Comment: @ChadMurray Edit it into your question, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @nightcracker dangit. Very tired...

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to print the return value of `characterLine(..)`, i.e.

```
print characterLine(...)
```

this will print `None` because you are not using the `return` keyword in front of your expression. Setting

```
def characterLine(firstChar,secondChar,phrase):
    return '\n' + ((str(firstChar)+str(secondChar))*(len(phrase)/2)+len(phrase)%2* firstChar)
```

should return a value other than None (which you then can `print`).

Comment: I thought maybe he has seen the `lambda` syntax and confused it with the `def` syntax. But I'll remove the part on `lambda`.

Comment: Gotcha. I think the post is still better without it. +1 for spotting his problem, unlike the rest of us who just got wrapped up in the rest of that line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Be default, functions have an implied `return None` as the end.

An empty [return-statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) also returns `None`.

So, you just need to add the return-statement to your function.  Otherwis, the rest of it looks okay.  Good luck :-)